# How to remove extrusions white area from underneath footer

Tags: html, css, footer

Im making a site and at the end of the footer there is a rather large block of just white space (almost like an extra div) I've tried rewriting the html and the css but nothing seems to help. other pages of the site use the exact same code for the footer but they don't have the same problem

Im going to assume that the css isn't the problem because other pages work maybe its the way I close my divs; maybe an extra set of eyes can spot my error. Thanks.

```
           <footer id="site-footer">
     <section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="clearfix">


<div class="hidden-phone">
    <div class="span3 widget text-3 widget_text">
        <div class="widget-inner">          
            <div class="textwidget">
                <div style="text-align:center;">

                        <img src="images/2014/10/logo.png">
                            <h3>Apparel</h3>
                    <hr>
                        <p>Meet LA Apparel, a beautiful botique with remarkable details.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                   </div>




       <h1>------------Collections Go here----------</h1>          




                <div class="span12 social-icons clearfix">
                            <hr>
                        <h4><small>CONNECT WITH US:</small></h4>

                                                          <a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com" class="tip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-placement="bottom" title="Find us on Facebook"><i class="icon-facebook"></i></a>
                                                                                      <a target="_blank" href="http://www.twitter.com" class="tip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Find us on Twitter"><i class="icon-twitter"></i></a>
                                                                                      <a target="_blank" href="http://www.linkedin.com" class="tip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Find us on LinkedIn"><i class="icon-linkedin"></i></a>
                                                                                      <a target="_blank" href="http://www.pinterest.com" class="tip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Find us on Pinterest"><i class="icon-pinterest"></i></a>

               </div>
            </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     <HR>
                <div class="span12 clearfix">
                    <p class="pull-left">&copy;LA Apparel</p>
                                    </div>
            </footer>
        </section>   
    </body>
</html>



    #site-footer {
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
  padding: 40px 0 15px;
  position: relative;
}
#site-footer a {
  color: #2980b9;
}
#site-footer a:hover {
  color: #ae9e90;
}
#site-footer #category-accordion > li a.accordion-collapser {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
#site-footer #category-accordion > li > ul > li > a {
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 1px 6px;
}
#site-footer #category-accordion > li > ul > li:last-child > a {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
#site-footer h4 {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
#site-footer .social-icons a {
  padding: 5px;
}
#site-footer p {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
#site-footer hr {
  border-color: #F3F3F3 -moz-use-text-color #E3E3E3;
  border-top: 1px solid #333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #212625;
}
#site-footer .blog-posts article {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E3E3E3;
  padding: 10px 0 0;
}
#site-footer .blog-posts article:first-child {
  padding-top: 0px;
}
#site-footer .blog-posts article:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

CSS code is Not given. But you can try changing

```
<p class="pull-left">&copy;LA Apparel</p>
```

To

```
<div class="pull-left">&copy;LA Apparel</div>
```

As p tag margin top and bottom is 16px. or you can rest your css for p tag margin

Comment: Thanks, but no dice. I've updated my answer to contain the css aswell

Comment: Why don't you find the problem within the browser itself using inspect element. Select the element and look for the source of extra padding or margin directly.